# Вопрос по Makefile

Tags: makefile

Вот я могу написать Makefile в одну строчку. Зачем мне расписывать его, то есть каждый объектный файл отдельно. Какие бонусы дает мне это расписывание?

Comment: пишите так, как вам удобно (или так, как требует ваш начальник, если создание Makefile входит в ваши должностные обязанности). p.s. если вы укладываетесь в одну строку, то и сам Makefile (как и запуск программы *make*, его интерпретирующей) вам явно не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо, но все равно, зачем расписывать каждый файл отдельно? то есть например main.o, func.o и т д